# Modify SVG files to include width and height of graphic in SVG tag

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, svg

I've a lot of SVG files (several graphics like, dogs, trees, birds, buildings etc.), and they are from different sources from web. I need to define `height` and `width` of these SVGs.

**Example File:**

```
<svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 36 33" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path d="m18 0.0938-17.719 16.281h5.5625v15.531h24.312v-15.531h5.5625l-17.719-16.281z"/>
</svg>
```

I get the **width** and **height** of this:

```
var svg1 = document.getElementById('svg1');
console.log('client', svg1.clientWidth + 'x' + svg1.clientHeight);
```

And then modified the file with the results:

```
<svg width="630" height="577" viewBox="0 0 36 33" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path d="m18 0.0938-17.719 16.281h5.5625v15.531h24.312v-15.531h5.5625l-17.719-16.281z"/>
</svg>
```

I am experienced in javascript and c#, but I don't know a way to achieve this.

**P.S:** The reason I need this: My wordpress custom product designer plugin uses SVG files to design custom products, but those SVG files must have `width` and `height` for my plugin to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SVG from material-ui, wrap it inside an IconButton (and define the height and width here). The svg takes the dimensions of the parent.